# When to use "->" vs "." when dealing with structs?

Tags: c, gcc, struct

In a c struct when I assign to a pointer I have to use -> but do I have to use -> for such types as int.

For example

```
struct foo{
    struct foo* a;
    int         b;
}

struct foo* ptr = (struct foo*) malloc(sizeof( struct foo ));
```

What is correct

```
ptr->a = something;
ptr->b = 44;
```

or

```
ptr->a = something;
ptr.b = 44;
```

and for freeing do I have to free b as I do have to free a?

```
free(ptr->a);
free(ptr.b); // do i have to do this?
```

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: Hmm, does `ptr.b = 44;` even work? (And if so, which compiler?)

Comment: @user2864740 As mentioned in Potatoswatter's answer, it's a GCC extension.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, what nonsense! :|

Comment: @Barmar egads. *yuck*.

Comment: Surprisingly noone stated that `foo->bar` is essentially `(*foo).bar`, but just easier to type/read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a variable is a pointer to a datatype(user-defined) use "`->`"

Let's say the DEFAULT way of accessing a member in a struct is using "`.`"

```
typedef struct {
     int a;
     int b*;
     float f;
     float pf;
     myStruct next*;
     char* c;
}myStruct;

//accessing all its members by DEFAULT:
myStruct dataA;
int valA       = dataA.a;
int* pvalB     = dataA.b;
float valF     = dataA.f;
float* pf      = dataA.pf;
myStruct next* = dataA.c;
```

Note: all members are accessed using "`.`" regardless if they are pointer or not

Now, if you define a POINTER to a `myStruct` object:

```
myStruct *pdataA = &dataA;

int valA2       = pdataA->a;
int* pvalB2     = pdataA->b;
float valF2     = pdataA->f;
float* pf2      = pdataA->pf;
myStruct next2* = pdataA->c;
```

It's just like the "`->`" is derefencing `pdataA` first because that variable is a pointer and the members can't be access directly.

Also note, that syntax also works in `class`, `union`, and `bit fields`. As long as they are data-types with members.

To free an allocated struct object, just pass the pointer variable.

```
myStruct* pdataB = (myStruct*)malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
// some code here...
free(pdataB);
```

Just be sure you're freeing a `myStruct` object allocated from heap.(That is using the `malloc()`).

```
myStruct dataC;
myStruct pdataD* = dataC;
//free(dataC);   //invalid
//free(&dataC);  //invalid
//free(pdataD);   //invalid
```

If a member variable is separately allocated, also free it separately:

```
myStruct* pdataF = (myStruct*)malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
pdataF->b        = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 500);
pdataF->pf       = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * 700);
// some code here...
free(pdataF->b);         
free(pdataF->pf);
free(pdataF);       //free the main object last.

myStruct dataG;
dataG.b        = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 500);
dataG.pf       = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * 700);
// some code here...
free(dataG.b);         
free(dataG.pf);
//free(&dataG);  //invalid because it's not allocated.
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `.` on a pointer is a nonconforming GCC extension. It should be warning you.

You need to `free` everything you got from `malloc`. That is, take the result of the call to `malloc` and pass it to `free`. It's that simple. Do not `free` anything else.

Comment: So what is -> doing? I though it was a quick way of assigning to what it points to and not just the pointer itself.

Comment: @Zimm3r `->` accesses a member given a pointer to `struct` type.

Comment: So why would I have to do that with a int primitive?

Comment: @Zimm3r Did you get the `int` from `malloc`? No.

Comment: Do I have to free a though? lldb still allows access if I don't.

Comment: @Zimm3r Nobody arbitrates access, there is no concept of "allowed" or not. Accessing a memory block destroyed by `free` is allowed to crash somehow, but not guaranteed to generate an error condition.

Comment: Ok. Thanks I think I had the idea that free deletes the block not just frees it up.

Comment: What's the difference between "deletes the block" and "frees it up" ?

Comment: Which nonconforming GCC extension!? I don't see this documented anywhere, and it certainly doesn't work on any of my copies of GCC.

Answer (score 1):

`.` is used when accessing members of a struct using an object.
`->` is used when accessing members of a struct using a pointer.

so, `ptr->a = something;` is correct.

Also, you `free` something that you allocate. SO, instead of `free(ptr->a);` use `free(pt);`, since you allocated `ptr` not `ptr->a`

Comment: But then why does lldb allow me to still access ptr->a after freeing ptr?

Comment: It just means the memory doesn't belong to you anymore, but you still have the address, meaning you can access it but you shouldn't, that is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Using a pointer after you free it is undefined behavior. Anything can happen, including accessing what used to be there.

Comment: So is there a way to delete a struct then?

Comment: That's what freeing it does. Freeing a pointer tells the implementation that it's allowed to reuse that memory for some future call to `malloc`. But it might not need to reuse it right away.

Comment: If the stuct has been allocated using malloc, just free() the pointer that was returned to you by malloc. And after `free`ing, set `ptr=NULL;`, so that you don't access it further in your program.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use -> for both a and b

```
ptr->a = something;
ptr->b = 44;
```

To free you can use

```
free (ptr); /* since ptr is what we got from malloc() */
```